# python issue can't load functions

Tags: python

So i'm using the mit computer science lectures to learn python but i'm having trouble advancing past the functions lecture/assignment. basically I wrote a function designed to find the square root of `x`. `sqrt(x)` is what i'm using to call it in the python 2.7 shell. Originally I copied it down myself but i was having issues so I copied the function from the handout but I'm still having the same problem. Basically in the lecture we created the function to find the square roots. when I run the file in terminal it doesn't return any code. just sends me to the next line like nothing happened. and when i do `sqrt(16)` in the python shell it gives me an error saying`'sqrt' is not defined`'. 
here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXR9CDof7qw&list=PL57FCE46F714A03BC&index=4 the part I'm referring to starts at 11:38. and here's the function copied directly from the handout. it's all indented the same as in the video so I don't think that's a problem.

```
def sqrt(x):
  """Returns the square root of x, if x is a perfect square.
       Prints an error message and returns None otherwise"""
  ans = 0
  if x >= 0:
      while ans*ans < x: ans = ans + 1
      if ans*ans != x:
          print x, 'is not a perfect square'
          return None
      else: return ans
  else:
        print x, 'is a negative number'
        return None
def f(x): 
    x=x+1
    return x
```

edit: copy and pasted @JaredJenson 's code into the python shell and got this error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w7RL.jpg when I ran it. the video I posted above shows the professor writing his function in notepad and then running it in the python shell by typing `sqrt(16)`. When I do that I get an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>

 sqrt(16)

NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
```

I"m not sure where it's going wrong. It should be outputting 4.

Comment: Did you try _calling_ the function...?

Comment: By the way you haven't indented f the same as in the video -_-

Comment: @coldspeed I thought I was by typing sqrt(16) in the python shell. at least that's what the video lead me to believe. am I missing something?

Comment: @AndreasGrivas my mistake. i copied this from the pdf notes. i think they were condensed. edited.

Comment: What did you type into the python shell? What happened?

Comment: @pvg it pauses and then just returns a new line. https://imgur.com/a/ULo96 the file name is correct. it's worked previously but not when I do functions

Comment: That doesn't show you typing anything in the python REPL, you're just typing things in the regular OS shell. The code you're telling the interpreter to run never invokes your function. Where are you typing `sqrt(16)` like you claim? What does it tell you when you type that?

Comment: this is what happens when i post it in the shell https://imgur.com/a/kMvd8    the picture shows what happens the last few times i tried to run the script

Comment: Did you type the entire function in the shell? Instead of posting screenshots, edit your question to describe exactly what you did, step by step, where, what output/prompts you got at each step, etc.

Comment: @pvg I copy and pasted the code from jared jensen and got that error message

Comment: @amnmustafa15 that's not what I asked you to do. Edit your question. What you did, where, what happened, what output you got, when, what you expected, etc. Take a look at [ask]

Comment: @pvg ok edited.

Comment: That still doesn't really say much. There is something slightly different in every one of your versions. You say the python shell, but you mean the OS shell. You say you typed sqrt(16) but then post a screenshot where you typed `print sqrt(16)`. Seriously, post a step by step description of _one_ of the things you did (maybe pasting the code), including the code, including the output, including the error, in text, not screenshots. This is super simple. It should be possible to read your question and reproduce what you did.

Comment: One possible reason you're getting hugely confused is the prof in that video is not editing files in Notepad, he's using the little IDE that comes with Python - IDLE. Maybe that's explained earlier and you missed it. You should read up on using that if you want to follow along in the course exactly as what you see in the video.

Comment: @pvg I solved it. Jared Jensen was on to something. I copied and pasted the original code into the python 2.7.13 shell and ran it separate from the other definition. I got 4 when i ran sqrt(16). I will try and be more in depth when i post questions in the future.

Comment: You might find it easier to use IDLE like the prof does anyway. Comes with Python, you have it installed. And keep in mind, the main purpose of the site is not to help _you_ solve your problem, it's to help others who might run into similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're defining the function in a separate place from where you're executing it. There are three options here.

1. Copy and paste the entire sqrt function into the python shell, and then run sqrt(16).

If you do this, your shell should look like this:

```
def sqrt(x):
  """Returns the square root of x, if x is a perfect square.
       Prints an error message and returns None otherwise"""
  ans = 0
  if x >= 0:
    while ans*ans < x: ans = ans + 1
    if ans*ans != x:
      print x, 'is not a perfect square'
      return None
    else: return ans
  else:
    print x, 'is a negative number'
    return None

print sqrt(16)
```

After you copy and paste that whole thing into your python 2.7 shell, it should print out a 4 at the end

2. Keep the whole thing in a file, and run the file

All you need to do here is copy and paste the above code into a file (let's call it mysqrt.py) and then run

```
python mysqrt.py
```

on the command line

3. Import your file and run the command from the shell

What you'll do here is the same as #2, except you delete the last line (print sqrt(16)) from the file.

Then, save your file, and make sure you're cd'd into the same directory that the file is in.

Start up the python interpreter

```
python
```

import your function

```
>>> from mysqrt import sqrt
```

then run it

```
>>> print(sqrt(16))
```

Comment: I started with step one and your code but this is what I got when I ran it. https://imgur.com/4W5EUVG

Comment: It looks like the copy/paste isn't pasting right. You may have to copy/paste the def part and the print part separately, or possibly even type it all out by hand again (which I recommend against). Probably the best thing to do is #2 or #3 here.

Comment: I tried a variation of your idea and copy/pasted the original code separate from the second definition. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over step by step how using the Python shell works, and see if we can figure out where you've gone wrong.

1. You open the shell, e.g. from the command line with `python`, or by using a shell window in IDLE or another IDE.
2. You see the `>>>` prompt, and you start typing the code for the function.
3. Each time you hit enter while inputting the function, you see a `...` prompt at the beginning of the next line.
4. You let the shell know that you're done writing the function, by inputting a blank line (just hit enter again on an empty line).
5. The prompt goes back to `>>>`.
6. You attempt to call the function.

---

Edit, following your clarifying comment: it looks like what you're trying to do is save the code in a file, and then call the function defined there. Your screenshot does *not* show you using "the Python shell" (it shows you using the command line). Right now, your program file `britney.py` defines functions, but doesn't do anything with them.

There are a few ways you can test out the functions from here:

- You can just have the file include a call to the function at top level, after it's defined.
- You can start up the shell (from the same folder that your source file is in - use just `python` without a filename), and then `import` the *module* defined by your file (in the given example, you would `import britney`) and call the function from it (`britney.sqrt(64)`).
- You can start up the shell, and then `import` the function directly (`from britney import sqrt`) and call it (`sqrt(64)`).
- You can run the file with the `-i` command-line option (`python -i britney.py`), which lets you "inspect" the program state after it runs - you get a Python shell, so after that you can call `sqrt` yourself.

Answer (score -1):

```
def sqrt(x):
    ans = 0
    if x >= 0:
        while ans*ans < x: ans = ans + 1
        if ans*ans != x:
             print(x, 'is not a perfect square')
             return None
        else:
             return ans
    else:
        print(x, 'is a negative number')

print(sqrt(4))      
print(sqrt(5))

>>>
2
5 is not a perfect square
None
```

---

Looks works for me on Python3, please make sure your indent